# SPLimitedWebpartManager resetting custom web part properties on SaveChanges

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

We are running a SharePoint 2013 publishing site in 2010 mode. A section of the code which used to work fine in 2010 is not working after I installed the SharePoint 2013 CTP update (Configuration database version:
15.0.4815.1000).

I am trying to add a custom webpart with custom properties. The below code adds the webpart to the correct zone but when SPLimitedWebPartManager.SaveChanges(webpart) executes, it resets the custom property values to default values.

```
var wpManager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(page.ListItem.Url, System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared)
var dsWebPart = new DocumentSetBridge()
        {
            Title = "Shared Resource(s)",
            ChromeType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeType.None,
            KnowledgeCenterAssetsLibraryItemId = documentSetUniqueGuid,
            ID = KnowledgeCenterSettings.DocumentSetBridgeWebPartId,
            ShowManageDocLink = true,
            IsUserCommunityDS = true
        };
wpManager.AddWebPart(dsWebPart, UserGroupSettings.DOCUMENTSET_WEBPART_ZONE_ID, UserGroupSettings.DOCUMENTSET_WEBPART_ZONE_INDEX);
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Senthil S

**UPDATE**: Found the issue with permissions. It creates a new page with pre-defined webparts and assigns the user manage rights just for the page. Eventhough, the page is updated with proper permissions, it seems like SP is not recognizing it until sometime later. It could be because of some timing issue. If I add the web part impersonating as an admin everything looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the WebPart to the SPLimitedWebPartManager you should do the following

```
wpManager.SaveChanges(dsWebPart);
web.Update();
```

and/or use [SetPersonalizationDirty()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157359(v=vs.110).aspx) like

```
dsWebPart.SetPersonalizationDirty();
```

Comment: I wish I could use that. But as it is inheriting from SP webpart, I do not have the option to use SetPersonalizationDirty() method.